# Why isn't my variable printing?

Tags: java, while-loop, println

```
 public class FirstofTen
 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
     int i = 10;

   while (i >= -10) {

      double x = i / 10.0;

      i--;

      String X = String.format("%.2f", x);

      System.out.println(X);        
    }

    i = 10; 

    while(i >= -10) {

      double x = i / 10.0;

      i--;

      String X = String.format("%.2f", x);

      double Y = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(1, 2) - Math.pow(x, 2));

      System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", Y));            
   }
```

This is a school assignment, I don't want an answer, just help. Basically, I am given that the hypotenuse of the triangle is always 1. I also know that `X` has to be between `-1` and `1`, and it has to be in the tenths place if its a double (`0.5`, `0.6`, etc.). So let's say `X` is `0.9`, then I have to let Java calculate the result of the third side of my triangle using the Pythagorean theorem. I got that part. The problem, I am having relies on the output. I get this output:

```
1.00
0.90
0.80
0.70
0.60
0.50
0.40
0.30
0.20
0.10
0.00
-0.10
-0.20
-0.30
-0.40
-0.50
-0.60
-0.70
-0.80
-0.90
-1.00
0.0
0.44
0.60
0.71
0.80
0.87
0.92
0.95
0.98
0.99
1.00
0.99
0.98
0.95
0.92
0.87
0.80
0.71
0.60
0.44
0.00
```

As you can see, it prints X and then it prints Y right below it. How can I separate them into different columns?

Comment: Where do you print `Y`?

Comment: Can you share the output you currently have and the output you're trying to get?

Comment: did you notice that the second printline has no argument?

Comment: and the second loop has the same condition as the first so it's always **false**

Comment: I suggest debugging your code.

Comment: OK, I originally copied the code incorrectly. Just debugged, and got the right values, but the formatting is still wrong. The question has been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  while (i >= -10){
     double x = i / 10.0;
     i--;
     String X = String.format("%.2f", x);
     System.out.println("X : " + X);
  }
```

When ***while*** loop exits the value for **i**  is **i = -1.0**

So, Your next while does not get executes as **i >= -10** returns ***false***

Solution :

```
int i=10;
System.out.print("Values For X : ");
while (i >= -10) {
   // Code Goes Here for first while loop
   System.out.print(" " + X)
}
i=10; // Just re-initialize i with previous value i.e., 10
System.out.print("Values For Y : ");
while(i>=-10) {
   // Code Goes Here for second while loop
    System.out.print(" " + Y);  // and not  System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I got it, but my output now has all the proper values of X and then all the proper values of Y. It's one giant column of numbers. How can I separate the columns, so X is on the left side and Y is on the right side? (P.S. The updated code is on my original post)

Comment: @Kush Update the Above Code as per your formatting Requirement

Comment: @Kush And If your problem is solved then Accept the answer so that it's visible to other users as being answered.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify what you want to print inside
`System.out.println();`instead:
`System.out.println(Y);`

Comment: You might want to clarify what you are attempting to say here.  The answer looks good to me, as an experienced programmer ... others may not understand as well.

Comment: I understood it, thanks! That was just a silly mistake when I was copying the code over to the forum.

Answer (score 0):

Your second while loop won't get entered because `i` is smaller than -10 after the first while loop. You should reset its value before the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code:

First, you shout reset your `i` back to ten at the start of the second loop; or use a `for` loop, it would be cleaner. That way, this code

```
int i = 10;
while (i >= -10) {
    // work
    i--;
}
```

becomes this:

```
for (int i = 10; i >=-10; i--) {
    // work
}
```

Secondly, in your second loop, you should format your `Y` and actually print it out. You can do the formatting and the printing in one go too:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", Y));
```

Answer (score 0):

initialize i=10 again in the code before second while loop it will work

Comment: Thanks! Now Y is printing, but it's printing right below X in terms of the output. I updated the question with more information, so how can I reformat Y so it is in a different column?

Comment: You can print it in same row by `System.out.println(X+"  "+String.format("%.2f", Y));`